# Azure ApplicationInsights using logback in Spring Boot - application name not propagated

Tags: spring-boot, azure-application-insights

Currently Im trying to integrate our Spring Boot Java services with Azure Application Insights.

First of all I shall write that below issue from 2018 seems to be still active/alive as I encountered this behavior when using 2.6.0 version.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/710

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/1014

It seems the application.yml (not properties in my case) are not used and I was able to get it working only with ApplicationInsgights.xml file.

Anyway there are some workarounds for setting the instrumentation key so OK.

However my question is following:

1. Why the Logback logs dont have application name in "**traces**" table/data set in Azure portal?
2. Under which column should the application name be populated? It was populated in column "**cloud_RoleName**", but now it is not populated despite no changes were made. Column "**appId**" is some UUID and column "**appName**" has name of the application insights resource, not the value from **spring.application.name**.

This doc does not seem up to date:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/traces

**Also the app. Im connecting to AI is run outside Azure, which can possibly play some role.**

Thanks.

Comment: appId and appName are the internal unique id and name of the application insights "app" resource.  they're generally used if you join across multiple app insights resources.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Regarding the real appName it seems the cloud_roleName is being populated only after some time, perhaps once the context is fully initialized. Lots of log messags/traces thus have this empty as per my visual check.